# FFmpeg Runtime Error.  Input/Output Error Returned

Tags: tcp, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I got error during tcp opening.
Exactly to say, `avformat_open_input` always return -5 (input/output error).
I looked into the source of the error code using gdb and found that `getaddrinfo`(in libavformat/tcp.c) function didn't work well as expected and returned the error value EIO.
My ffmpeg source have `ff_getaddrinfo`(in libavformat/os_support.c) function that is linked to `getaddrinfo`(which function is a pointer function) but when I run the program, my program called other function in libc.so(not getaddrinfo), dynamic library. I couldn't find which function is called.
I gave the valid url to ffmpeg. The valid url is "http://stream.radiojavan.com/radiojavan".

I compiled ffmpeg source for Android-use and used ffmpeg version 0.8.1
This is my configuration.

```
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --enable-zlib \
```

Any advise or help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add Internet permission to your Android Manifest and it may work.
"android.permission.INTERNET (Uses Permission)"